# Need hardware specification recommendation for a .NET4 WCF service server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, hardware, wcf, specifications

I need a rough HW specification recommendation for a server with the following SW and usage specs:

- Windows Server 2003 or 2008.
- One .Net4 WCF service hosted on IIS, or self-hosted.
- 100 concurrent internet users, about 1 req/client/minute.
- Mandatory SOAP message-based encryption with x.509 certificates for server and clients.
- PostgreSQL database on same machine with synchronous database replication to another server.

There should be a response of at most 2 seconds for a 2Mbps client's request that returns 1000 xml-serialized database rows (reasonably-sized typical rows, no documents or other BLOBs). Separating DB and WS on different servers should be avoided if possible.

I'd like to know things like CPU, RAM, etc. Storage size is not important, since it will directly be related to estimated DB size.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mobile phone.

16gb, 6xx of it RAM, 1 core, 1ghz.

Seriously.

This is about the level of need you talk here.

Comment: Thx, but what does "16gb, 6xx of it RAM" mean?

Comment: That my phone has 16gb storage, 6something (3 digits) megabytes of RAM. WAY more than needed for your "site".

Comment: I want to give this -1 because it deserves -1, but I also want to give it +2 because it's freaking hilarious.  Not sure what I should do.